# Can't select html elements with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a page (http://www.nextsteptutoring.co.uk/WhatWeTeach.html) with 4 selectable h3 elements that bring up further text on the topic for the user to read.

The 1st element works perfectly - the whole element is selectable. The 2nd and 3rd are partially selectable, the + and first letter can be clicked. The 4th can't be clicked at all.

The JS works fine and my CSS would seem to be fine as displayed by the 1st working fine, and the 2nd and 3rd being partially ok. I can't see how this could be a z-inex as the only element on the page with a z-index value is the footer, which loads fine as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv="content-type">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin+Condensed" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Main.CSS">
    <title>NST | What We Teach</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
    <header> </header>
    <div class="leftcolumn">
      <h2>What We Teach</h2>
      <p> Clear schemes of work, linked to the National Curriculum, which 
      are individually tailored to your child’s needs. We offer one to one          
      sessions, or small groups, with a maximum of 4 children. Groups are          
       based on specific needs/ability, rather than on chronological age.<br/>
      <br/>
      Programmes of study are adapted for high achievers in need of a
      challenge, as well as those who lack confidence or require additional
      support, outside of mainstream education.<br/>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="rightcolumn">
      <div class="hide">
        <h3>+ Primary Maths</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>The four rules of number</li>
          <li>Focus on Mental Arithmetic</li>
          <li>Multiplication and associated division facts</li>
          <li>Fractions, decimals and percentages</li>
          <li>Data Handling, measures, and shapes</li>
          <li>Algebra</li>
          <li>Using and applying mathematical skills in everyday problem
            solving</li>
          <li>Confidence building and catch-up</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="hide">
        <h3>+ Primary English</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Clear focus on comprehension. Building skills of inference and
            reasoning</li>
          <li>Individually tailored spelling programme (specialised dyslexia
            spelling programme)</li>
          <li>Grammar and punctuation</li>
          <li>Writing for different purposes and audiences</li>
          <li>Handwriting</li>
          <li>Confidence building and catch-up</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="hide">
        <h3>+ Year 6 to Year 7 Transition</h3>
        <p>Tailored English and Maths programme to support youngsters who 
          lack confidence during their transition from Primary to Secondary
          education.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="hide">
        <h3>+ Written Reports</h3>
        <p>Parents may wish to receive a termly or yearly written report on
          their child’s progress, and targets for the next phase of their
          learning. This service will incur a fee of £10.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer> </footer>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("header").load("Header.txt");
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("footer").load("Footer.txt");
    });
    $(".hide > h3").click(function(){ 
      $(this).parent().toggleClass("show");
    });
    $(".show > h3").click(function(){
      $(this).parent().toggleClass("hide");
    }); 
  </script>
</body>
</html>


footer {
   position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   background: rgba(150,150,150,1);
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   z-index: 5;
}
footer .container div {
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 5px 30px 2px 30px;
}
#contact {
   background: rgba(120,117,185,1);
   float: right;
   padding: 5px 100px 2px 100px;
}
.hide h3 {
   width: 100%;
   background: rgba(171,167,242,0.75);
   border-radius: 5px;
   cursor: pointer;
   padding: 2px 0 2px 8px;
}
.hide p, .hide ul {
   opacity: 0;
   height: 0;
}
.show {
   height: auto;
}
.show p, .show ul {
   opacity: 1;
   list-style-type: square;
   height: auto;
   font-size: 18px;
}
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `css`.

Add this:

```
.hide p, .hide ul {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

The `li` elements were overlapping the buttons. So give `overflow: hidden` to the `ul` and they get `hidden` properly without affecting the rest.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
.hide h3 {
  padding: 2px 0 2px 10px;
  width: 97%;
  background: rgba(171,167,242,0.75);
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
```

Add `position:relative` CSS property to your `.hide h3` it will work fine.